# Wordpress do__shortcode() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want slider on the shop page in the woocommerce product page on top i am adding the do_shortcode() but not working when i am using that shortcode in the post this is working good but in template not working as well i use apply_filters() but not working.i try both but not working ?

```
 <?php echo apply_filters('the_content','[layerslider id="5"]'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[layerslider id="5"]');?>
```